# Is there an open data feed of storm tracks in the Asia-Pacific region?

Tags: data-request

I'm trying to make a web map visualizing the active typhoons and I'm missing the data for the typhoon tracks. Anybody know where I can get the data? Preferably in JSON/GeoJSON but WFS and WMS are fine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is!  The real-time datasets related to hurricane, cyclone, and typhoon tracks is at the [National Hurricane Center](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/).

Note that people use the terms hurricanes, cyclones, and typhoons interchangeably (as noted by the U.S. [National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/cyclone.html)):

```
Hurricanes, cyclones, and typhoons are all the same weather phenomenon; we just use different names for these storms in different places. In the Atlantic and Northeast Pacific, the term “hurricane” is used. The same type of disturbance in the Northwest Pacific is called a “typhoon” and “cyclones” occur in the South Pacific and Indian Ocean.
```

Hurricane track data is provided by NOAA's National Weather Service, and you can find [historic tracks for the Pacific](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/past-east-pacific-storm-tracks) and [Atlantic](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/past-atlantic-storm-tracks).